# Loading assembly dll in powershell doesnt work anymore

Tags: powershell

I have an exchange script that contains this:

```
$dllpath = "C:\assembly\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
```

And this did work on my previous system but on my current systen when trying to run this, I get an error message that I want to load an assembly from a remote storage and that sandbox assenblys are disabled in this .net version and that I need to add a 'loadFromRemoteSource' flag to the config. There is also this link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569

What do I need to do?

Comment: If the dll comes from Internet the file is probably blocked. Try `Unblock-File` on the dll. Or Properties of the files with a GUI.

Comment: @Hazrelle Still the same error message after unblocking

Comment: May it be possible the C:\ drive or path to this file especially has been assigned in a specific Internet Explorer zone (Local Intranet, Internet, Trusted Sites or Restricted Sites) ?

Comment: Wow, that could be it. I copied the dll to an usb drive and that did fix the loading issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: Nice, glad this helped.